# Understanding OpenGL state associations

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been using OpenGL for quite a while now but I always get confused by it's state management system.  In particular the issue I struggle with is understanding exactly which object or target a particular state is stored against.

Eg 1: assigning a texture parameter.  Are those parameters stored with the texture itself, or the texture unit?  Will binding a texture with a different texture unit move those parameter settings?

Eg 2: glVertexAttribPointer - what exactly is that associated with - is the it the active shader program, the the bound data buffer, the ES context itself?  If I bind a different vertex buffer object, do I need to call glVertexAttribPointer again?

So I'm not asking for answers to the above questions - I'm asking if those answers are written down somewhere so I don't need to do the whole trial and error thing everytime I use something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those answers are written in the [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) (PDF link). Every function states what state it affects, and there's a big series of tables at the end that specify which state is part of which objects, or just part of the global context.